# How to create multiple files in downloads then append them in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a button that takes an input file and manipulates it I would like to first create the new files them append them so I'm only reading smaller slices of data to not overload the browser if I tried to open a very large file.

```
    function SplitFile(){
      num_files = document.getElementById("piece-up").value;

      var control = document.getElementById("your-files");
      files = control.files;
      len = files.length;

      var test = document.getElementById("test");
      test.value = '';
      var i = 0;
      while (i < len){
        test.value += i + "\n";
        test.value += "Filename: " + files[i].name;
        test.value += "\n" + "Type: " + files[i].type;
        test.value += "\n" + "Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes";

        var file_length = files[i].size;
        var slice_size = 100;
        var remainder = file_length % slice_size;
        var num_large = file_length - remainder;
        var num_loops = num_large / slice_size;
        var slice_0 = 0;
        var slice_1 = slice_size;
        var q = 0;
        test.value += "\n" + "Num Loops: " + num_loops;

        while(q< num_loops){
          var myReader = new FileReader();
          myReader.readAsText(files[i].slice(slice_0, slice_1));
          myReader.onload = function(event) {
            test.value += "\n" + "Loop: " + q;
            var contents = event.target.result;
            test.value += "\n" + contents;
            spliceContents(num_files, contents, slice_size);
          };
          slice_0 = slice_0 + slice_size;
          slice_1 = slice_1 + slice_size;
          q++;
        }
        var myReader = new FileReader();
        slice_0 = slice_1 - slice_size;
        slice_1 = slice_1 + remainder - slice_size;
        myReader.readAsText(files[i].slice(slice_0, slice_1));
        myReader.onload = function(event) {
          test.value += "\n" + "Loop: " + q;
          var contents = event.target.result;
          test.value += "\n" + contents;
        };
        i++;
      }

    }

function spliceContents(num_files, contents, slice_size) {
  var i = 0;
  while(i<slice_size){
    var mod = i % num_files;
    appendFile(mod, contents[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

function appendFile(mod, contents){

}
```

Comment: Should I add a delay between opening files because the order the data is added to the file matters because I want to be able to retrieve this data??

Comment: Not certain what Question is ? Though `FileReader` returns results asynchronously. How would browser "overload" ? What is a "very large file" ?

Comment: Very large file like gbs of data and java in the browser would crash